# how to implement device orientation in html5 with phaser framework

Tags: javascript, html, device-orientation, phaser-framework

I am trying to make a simple game with phaser framework which uses device orientation API , i tried to do it but the movement is not done. 
here is the code
`

preload: function() {

```
    game.stage.backgroundColor = '#64FE2E';
    game.load.image('gau','assets/ball.png');
},

create: function() { 

    this.ball = this.game.add.sprite(100,245, 'gau');

},

update: function() {
    // Function called 60 times per second
    if(this.ball.inWorld == false)
       this.restart_game();
        keys = this.game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", this.handleOrientation, true);
},

handleOrientation: function(e) {
var x = e.gamma; // range [-90,90]
var y = e.beta;  // range [-180,180]
this.ball.body.velocity.x -= x*2;
this.ball.body.velocity.y -= y*4;
```

},
`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a scope issue. The 'this' inside handleOrientation will refer to 'window'.

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", this.handleOrientation, true);

handleOrientation: function(e) {
  var x = e.gamma; // range [-90,90]
  var y = e.beta;  // range [-180,180]
  // looking for reference to ball on the window object
  this.ball.body.velocity.x -= x*2;
  this.ball.body.velocity.y -= y*4;
}
```

One way round this is to 'bind' the handleOrientation method to the current scope like so:

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", this.handleOrientation.bind(this), true);

handleOrientation: function(e) {
  var x = e.gamma; // range [-90,90]
  var y = e.beta;  // range [-180,180]
  // this now refers to the game object
  this.ball.body.velocity.x -= x*2;
  this.ball.body.velocity.y -= y*4;
}
```